# How to detect google play subscription charge in google play developer API?

Tags: google-api, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I want to know about all subscriptions payments of my android app. Is this possible by the API? I can get information about subscription statuses changes and calculate charges. But I can make mistake in this calculations, so is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `SUBSCRIPTION_RENEWED` notification type in google real-time developer notifications see https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications